# Flex Multi-Language App with Hebrew and Romana

Tags: android, apache-flex, hebrew

I'm doing a multi language program, it have different language include the hebrew & romana.

I'm having few problem with the Capability.language, it returns Error or null when I change the device language to hebrew or romana and set English as default language, I need to know the device language to print some images that they are associate to the Currency ISO Codes by Country and I can know it with the device language. So how can i know the language device (it's an android device and the program is a Flex program with AIR) when they're hebrew or romana.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capabilities.languages returns an array of languages in the preferred order.  So if you do this:

```
var prefLang : String;
var langs : Array = Capabilities.languages;
```

Then check if it is there:

```
 if(langs) {
        // your preferred language is the first one
        prefLang = langs[0];
   } else {
      prefLang = Capabilities.language;
   }
```